# Performing Operations on metrics using Grafana and Bucky and OpenTSDB

Tags: opentsdb, grafana

So we are currently trying out Grafana using the data source OpenTSDB. And the metrics are being fed into OpenTSDB using Bucky (javascript). Unfortunately Bucky feeds the raw metrics like .navigationStart or .domComplete. But what we need are metrics that are already computed and more meaningful, like "Total Page Load Time" and etc. like in SiteSpeed.io.

like:

Total Page Load Time = performance.timing.loadEventEnd – performance.timing.navigationStart

To address this I was thinking of computing these values myself, however Grafana's metric input for OpenTSDB don't seem to have operations like that (like for its support for Graphite which has diffSeries to do subtraction)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you open to considering other NoSQL databases that can compute derived metrics including a product of two irregular time-series?

Comment: sure.. although my alternative is Graphite if i still can't find anything for this Grafana <-> Bucky <-> OpenTSDB setup. any suggestions?